# Using video recorded by iPad how can I calculate the exact time duration between 2 frames?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, camera

I shot a video with an iPad recently for a school project.

My teacher told me the iPad shoots at 30 fps, but opening the video afterwards VLC tells me the frame rate is 29.970030.

By watching the video and stepping through the frames, **how can I calculate the exact time duration between 2 frames?**

E.g. what's the time difference between frame 100 and frame 130? Is it 1 second (assuming 30 fps) or slightly more/less?

Comment: @oa- why did you add the iPhone tag?

Comment: The frame rates apply to the camera of iPads and iPhones to the same degree since Apple uses the same camera modules for both devices with the same software.

Answer (score 1):

iOS' native camera app (iPhone/iPad) does not have a fixed frame rate.

I attached the details for a short clip I recorded. It varies between 28.571 fps and 30.000 fps

[image: Frame Rate for iOS video]

VLC displays a frame rate of **29.973708 fps** for the same clip.

Comment: What about "how can I calculate the exact time duration between 2 frames?"

Answer (score 1):

29.97* is a Standard... an odd standard but a standard nevertheless.
It is commonly known as **[drop-frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode#Drop_frame_timecode)**

You can read the entire wikipedia article, but basically it was a kludge to make analog 30fps broadcasts not display odd interference patterning based on the frequency of the picture sub-code & sound sub-code. [You really don't need to know all this ;)
The 'drop frame' is really not dropping frames; it's dropping time code so that it doesn't eventually go out of sync.

The picture should actually still be running at 30fps, in "real" time.

The formula, btw is 30/1.001 - though being a kludge in the first place it doesn't quite work like that...

> That is, drop frame TC drops 18/18000 frame numbers, equivalent to
>   1/1000, achieving 30×0.999 = 29.97 frame/s. This is very slightly
>   slower than the true NTSC frame rate of 30/1.001 = 29.97002997
>   frame/s, which is equivalent to dropping 1/1001 frame numbers. The
>   difference is one additional NTSC frame per 1,000,000 drop frame TC
>   values, which is negligible.

This one you can truly blame the Americans & the NTSC** television standard for - the rest of the world went with a far more sensible 25fps which never needed this workaround.

*or more precisely, depending which way you calculate it, 29.97002997
**NTSC stands for Never Twice the Same Colour ;-)

Comment: Do you know how I can calculate the exact time duration between 2 frames?

Comment: https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=D%26section=6%26tasks=true 1 Frame = 1/29.97s = 1.001s

Comment: According to oa- though the frame rate is variable. Is that documentation specifically about iPad footage because from my brief scan it seems to be just general about drop frame recordings.